# How to Sort Text File Contents by First Name in PHP?

Tags: php, sorting, text

I have a html form that provides users to enter user/email, first and last name, and comments. I did write user inputs to a text file and it displayed successfully. I got problem when sorting all of the user information in the text file.

I'm trying to sort a text file's content by first name.
my txt content looks like below:

aaaaaaaaaaa

cccccc

bbbbbbb

Bob
Lebeau
fsdfsadf@yahoo.com
fsdfsd

the text file contains several blocks of username/email, first name, last name, and comment. 
I used sort() in order to output ascending sort, but it's not working.

Someone could help me to sort the file content by first name in ascending order?

```
function writeText(){
global $filename,$fName,$lName,$acc,$comments,$input,$arr;

echo "<br>Done. Inputs written to Guest Book.txt<br>";
$fileHandler=fopen($filename,"ab");
flock($fileHandler,LOCK_EX);//Writing lock

fwrite($fileHandler,$input);//accept $filename


if(file_exists($filename)){
    $fileHandler = fopen($filename,"r");

    while(!feof($fileHandler)){
        //read line by line
        echo fgets($fileHandler)."<br>";
        echo fgetss($fileHandler,4096)."<br>";

    }
    fclose($fileHandler);

$text=file_get_contents($filename);         
$textArr=explode("\n",$text);
foreach ($textArr as $texts) {
    if($texts)
        $new_arr[] = explode("\n", $texts);
}
 function sort_arr($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]); 
    // 0 index will be first name
}
usort($new_arr, "sort_arr");
foreach($new_arr as $v){
    echo implode("\n",$v)."\n";
}
print_r($textArr);
//display result
    echo "<br>Done. Contents have been sorted<br>";
}else{
    echo "<br>File dosen't exist";
}


if(empty($fName)&&empty($lName)&&empty($acc)&&empty($comments)){
    echo "<br>Nothing to display";

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have here? What does your input look like? What does your desired output look like?

Comment: I have a html form that provides users to enter user/email, first and last name, and comments. I did write user inputs to a text file and it displayed successfully. I got problem when sorting all of the user information in the text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggession is to diffrenciate rows and columns of your file.
While writing in file fname,lname,acc and comments should be seperated with`\t`. And new data will be separated with `\n`;

So after stored like this you can loop through your data , strore in array then sort that array by your first name

```
$input=$fName."\t".$lName."\t".$acc."\t".$comments."\n";
$filename="temp/Guest Book.txt";

function writeText(){
    global $filename,$fName,$lName,$acc,$comments,$input,$arr;

    echo "<br>Done. Inputs written to Guest Book.txt";
    $fileHandler=fopen($filename,"ab");
    flock($fileHandler,LOCK_EX);//Writing lock

    fwrite($fileHandler,$input);//accept $filename
//  flock($fileHandler,LOCK_UN);//Unlock

    if(file_exists($filename)){
        $fileHandler = fopen($filename,"r");

        while(!feof($fileHandler)){
            //read line by line
            echo fgets($fileHandler)."<br>";
            echo fgetss($fileHandler,4096)."<br>";

        }
        fclose($fileHandler);

    $text=file_get_contents($filename);         
    $textArr=explode("\n",$text);
    foreach ($textArr as $texts) {
        if($texts)
            $new_arr[] = explode("\t", $texts);
    }

     function sort_arr($a, $b)
    {
        return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]); // 0 index will be first name
    }

    usort($new_arr, "sort_arr");
    //var_dump($new_arr); //display result
     foreach($new_arr as $v){
         echo $v[0]." ".$v[1]." ".$v[2]." ".$v[3]."<br>";
      }
        echo "<br>Done. Contents have been sorted<br>";
    }else{
        echo "<br>File dosen't exist";
    }
    if(empty($fName)&&empty($lName)&&empty($acc)&&empty($comments)){
        echo "<br>Nothing to display";

    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for the correction but it doesn't work. I'm thinking if I could make one block of user information one element of an array, then sort by first name

Comment: I have tested this code work fine for me. what issue are you getting

Comment: Oh ok I got what you mean. But I have to sort it by first name block by block, I mean like one user's information is like one element of an array

Comment: use `foreach` loop to traverse array and print your value

Comment: it gives me error: Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: Yes I just pasted them

Comment: I got it with implode() function. Thank you for all the help and your time